# Can we process infinite matrices with a quantum computer?

Tags: matrix-representation, mathematics

Can we process infinite matrices with a quantum computer?

If then, how can we do that?

Comment: why do you think it should be possible? also, define "represent" here.

Comment: @glS Firstly, what I mean by **represent** is to store to make it be ready for processing(Classical computingly, loading the matrix on memory).

Comment: @glS Also the reason why I thought it would be possible: When Schrodinger proved that his wave-function equation can derive Heigenberg's matrix mechanics, he substituted functions to infinite vectors, and operators to infinite matrices, right? Then I thought reversely. Does it sounds silly..?

Comment: you can always "represent" infinite matrices with finite memory, but you don't need anything quantum for that. Indeed, I can do it in this chat: *let "2" represent an "infinite-dimensional" diagonal matrix with all entries equal to 2*. You can probably see why this way of "representing" isn't particularly useful nor revealing. If on the other hand what you are asking is whether quantum computers can be used to store an infinite amount of information (in a useful way), then the answer is no, they cannot.

Comment: KYHSGeekCode, I don't think it's a silly question. But to follow up on gIS, please also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo%27s_theorem - especially the part that states "given n qubits, although they can 'carry' a larger amount of (classical) information (thanks to quantum superposition), the amount of classical information that can be retrieved, i.e. accessed, can be only up to n classical (non-quantum encoded) bits."

Comment: @glS you can *sometimes "represent"

Comment: @AHusain yes, of course, I didn't mean to say that any "infinite matrix" can be represented with finite memory, but rather that it can be trivial to represent *some* kinds of infinite-dimensional objects with a finite amount of memory (the catch clearly being what "represent" is taken to mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If instead of manipulating the quantum information in qubits, your quantum computer were to do operations on qu$d$its with $d$ being infinity, then you'd essentially be processing infinite matrices on a quantum computer.

However most quantum computing hardware we have today, and even most of the experiments being done in academic labs, do operations on qubits (such as spin-1/2 nuclei), rather than on qu$d$its with an infinite value for $d$ (such as a quantum harmonic oscillator).

It is theoretically possible to do quantum gates on qu$d$its with infinite $d$, which would be processing infinite matrices, but it is not done in practice. It is hard enough to make quantum computers with ~100 qubits (which would still be processing only finite-dimensional matrices).

Comment: Thanks. Then do you think quantum computers manipulating something like quantum harmonic oscilator to operate with qu**d**its with infinite value d will be built if needed in the near future?

Comment: [These guys](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/computing/hardware/qudits-the-real-future-of-quantum-computing) have confirm the realization of a quantum system with at least one hundred dimensions, formed by two entangled qudits with D = 10. 
[Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature22986) is the paper.

Comment: @epr_guy That seems innovative. Can D be infinity practically? Or D is just a large number(finite) anyway even with technical advance? (I mean can we use **real** infinity? Or just theoretically?)

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode What do you mean by **real** infinity? $\omega$?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode To excite the higher energy eigenvalues of a harmonic oscillator requires higher energy. So you have to keep in mind the energy required to operate such a system.

Comment: @meowzz I wanted to know whether D is mathematical $\infty$ or a large number that can grow without upper limit(but can never be $\infty$)

Comment: @biryani OK, I'll keep it in my mind. But what do you mean by exciting eigen**value**, an abstract one...?

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: "the fundamental difference between the CV model and the traditional qubit model is that in the CV model, we formally apply operations on infinite-dimensional instead of two-dimensional systems."-[Juan Miguel Arrazola](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4167/2645)

Comment: @Juan what do you mean by "CV model"? (Late question:( )